# How to write XAML for TreeView with Dictionary and nested lists?

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview

I am writing an application for teachers and students in which a teacher can lookup grades of his students based on a selected subject.

In order to group everything together I have created a dictionary which contains all grades of students in a selected subject (e.g. all grades from Math, it doesn't really matter here):

```cs
IDictionary<Class, List<KeyValuePair<Student, List<Grade>>>>
```

**Class** is a key to this dictionary which is just a class that students belong to. It has a name of type string that I would like to display (e.g. "4F")

Value is a list that contains a **Students** from given class and a list of his/her **Grades** (every Grade has Value and Description, e.g. 3- and "Algebra exam", I would like to display them too).

Basically what I would like to see for every Class (which means for every Key in a dictionary) is something like this (number of students and grades may vary):

- ClassName

  - Student

    - Grade - Description
  - Student2

    - Grade - Description
    - Grade2 - Description

I've been looking for a solution, I think it might involve using `<TreeView.Resources>` and `<HierarchicalDataTemplate>` but to be honest I don't really understand how to use them. I tried one solution and displayed only every ClassName and Students that are connected with a class, but couldn't display anything else. Another solution suggested here: [Simple Nested TreeView Xaml structure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28993566/simple-nested-treeview-xaml-structure) left me with:

```
[SchoolerDatabaseUtilities.Class,System.Collections.Generic.List'1[System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair'2[SchoolerDatabaseUtilities.Student,System.Collections.Generic.List'1[SchoolerDatabaseUtilities.Grade]]]]
```

written for every Key that I had in a dictionary (SchoolerDatabaseUtilities is just a library that I use in order to keep everything in my files clean).

Please help me with anything because I don't even know where to start...

It was suggested that my question was a duplicate of [WPF TreeView hierarchical binding.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12532435/wpf-treeview-hierarchical-binding) but to me it doesn't seem like it. I was using Dictionary, not a List<>() and it seems to me that my problem was slightly harder in it's nature (whether my approach to a problem was good in terms or readability or not).

Comment: Though the `Dictionary` is useful for behind the scenes, when it comes to a ViewModel you probably want to copy the items into an `ObservableCollection`.  Then I would have thought the solution in the link you provided straight-forward?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WPF TreeView hierarchical binding.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12532435/wpf-treeview-hierarchical-binding)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have.to use the  [`HierarchicalDataTemplate`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.hierarchicaldatatemplate?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev16.query%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Windows.HierarchicalDataTemplate)%3Bk(VS.XamlEditor)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework%2CVersion%3Dv4.7.2)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=netframework-4.8#examples).

But  you should try to rework your design and build your types to explicitly reflect the tree data structure - without nested collections. This means `Class` should have a child collection of type `Student` and `Student` a child collection of type `Grade`. Then `Class` or a collection of `Class` would become the root of your tree (the `ItemsSource` binding source of the whole `TreeView`). If you would have done this, then the templates could have the `DataType` property set, which would make all the type casts redundant. It's also much more convenient to work with and improves readability.

```
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding TreeSource}">
  <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
    <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Value}">
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding Key.(Class.Name)}" />

      <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Value}">
          <TextBlock Text="{Binding Key.(Student.Name)}" />

          <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate DataType="Grade">
              <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Value}" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Description}" />
              </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
          </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
      </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
  </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
</TreeView>
```

Comment: I followed your advice and redesigned how I am storing all information and after some tweaking in my XAML I got it working. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I followed [BionicCode](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3141792/bioniccode)'s advice and [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/dotnet/api/system.windows.hierarchicaldatatemplate?view=netframework-4.8) and made `List<Class>` where every Class has `List<Student>` and every Student has `List<Grade>` which made everything better and easier.
After all my code looks like this:

```cs
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding MyListOfClasses}">
    <TreeView.Resources>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type utilities:Class}" ItemsSource="{Binding StudentList}">
               <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type utilities:Student}" ItemsSource="{Binding GradesList}">
               <TextBlock Text="{Binding FullNameRev}" />
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type utilities:Grade}">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="75" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="500" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Value}" Grid.Column="0"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Description}" Grid.Column="1"/>

            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </TreeView.Resources>
</TreeView>
```

where utilities is defined in my `<UserControl>` tag as a:

```
xmlns:utilities="clr-namespace:SchoolerDatabaseUtilities;assembly=SchoolerDatabaseUtilities"
```

And `SchoolerDatabaseUtilities` is my library with definition of all of these classes

Comment: Exactly! Much better now.