# Binding observable collection to a TreeView in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, linq, observablecollection, collectionviewsource

Thanks in advance,

I want to bind an observable collection to a TreeView in WPF such that it should display the each TreeView Node as a CountryType. The TreeView is bound to this collection from code behind.

Here's the code :

```
public partial class MyUserControl: UserControl
{
    public ObservableCollection<Person> myList { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<PersonViewModel> PersonViewModelList { get; set; }

     public MyUserControl()
     {
       InitializeComponent();
       PopulateCollection();
       DataContext = this;
     }

     private void PopulateCollection()
        {
            myList = new ObservableCollection<Person>()
            {
                new Person{ Name="Name 1", Age=21, CountryType = CountryList.India},
                new Person{ Name="Name 2", Age=21, CountryType = CountryList.US},
                new Person{ Name="Name 3", Age=24, CountryType = CountryList.Israel},
                new Person{ Name="Name 4", Age=24, CountryType = CountryList.Israel},
                new Person{ Name="Name 5", Age=24, CountryType = CountryList.Russia},
                new Person{ Name="Name 6", Age=24, CountryType = CountryList.India},
                new Person{ Name="Name 7", Age=24, CountryType = CountryList.Russia},
                new Person{ Name="Name 8", Age=24, CountryType = CountryList.Russia},
                new Person{ Name="Name 9", Age=24, CountryType = CountryList.Japan},
                new Person{ Name="Name 10", Age=24, CountryType = CountryList.Japan},
                new Person{ Name="Name 11", Age=24, CountryType = CountryList.India},
                new Person{ Name="Name 12", Age=24, CountryType = CountryList.India},
            };

            PersonViewModelList = myList.GroupBy(x => x.CountryType)
            .Select(g => new PersonViewModel()
            {
                CountryType = g.Key,
                Names = g.Select(x => x.Name).OrderBy(n => n).ToList()
            });          
        }
  }

  public class Person
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }
        public CountryList CountryType { get; set; }        
    }

    public class PersonViewModel
    {
        public CountryList CountryType { get; set; }
        public List<string> Names { get; set; }
    }

  public enum CountryList
    {
        India,
        Russia,
        US,
        Israel,
        Japan
    }
```

UserControl (XAML file)

```
 <TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding PersonViewModelList}">
        <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Names}" DataType="{x:Type local:PersonViewModel}">
                <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=CountryType}"></TextBlock>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
    </TreeView>
```

**Expected:**

[image]

I am pretty not sure what change I should do in TreeView to make it work.
Thanks again.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [WPF TreeView hierarchical binding.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12532435/wpf-treeview-hierarchical-binding).  Though your currernt data structure does **not** represent a hierarchy suitable for your screenshot

Comment: @MickyD : No, I tried that but looks like I am doing something wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current `Person` type is not suited or valid for your requirements. You need to transform your data into an hierarchical view model:

```
public class PersonViewModel
{
    public CountryList CountryType { get; set; }
    public List<string> Names { get; set; }
}
```

Just group your current `myList` by `CountryType` and bind to the result:

```
var transformedList = myList
    .GroupBy(x => x.CountryType)
    .Select(g => new PersonViewModel()
    { 
        CountryType = g.Key, 
        Names = g.Select(x => x.Name).OrderBy(n => n).ToList() 
    });
```

**XAML:**

```
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding PersonViewModelList}">
    <TreeView.Resources>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Names}" DataType="{x:Type local:PersonViewModel}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding CountryType}" />
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </TreeView.Resources>
</TreeView>
```

Comment: What change I may have to do in xaml ? Can you be a bit more clear ? Thanks.

Comment: You need to modify your view model code, not your XAML.

Comment: Yes, I made these changes, But I am not able to see the tree view getting displayed.

Comment: See my edit. You need to bind to the properties of the new type as well of course.

Comment: Thanks, It's pretty strange that I am not able to see the TreeView Still :(

Comment: Is `transformedList` returned from a public property`? Did you set the `DataContext` and bind the `ItemsSource` of the `TreeView`?

Comment: Yes, I am returning the transformed list to public IEnumerable<PersonViewModel> PersonViewModelList { get; set; }. I have also set the DataContext = this; in the contructor of UserControl. I have binded the PersonViewModelList  to the ItemSource of TreeView

Comment: @MishraSaurabh: And you don't see anything in the `TreeView`? I don't believe you then :) Please post your code. Did you debug to see if the property actually returns any data?

Comment: Please check the complete code in the post above. I have edited it. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry for the typo. Updated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to invert your data structure, something like this ...

```
var countyPeople = MyList.GroupBy(p => p.CountryType)
    .Select(g => new {Country = g.Key, People = g.ToList()})
    .OrderBy(c => c.Country)
    .ToList();
```

which you can then set as the ItemsSource of your TreeView.

The ItemsSource in your HierarchicalDataTemplate would then bind to the People property of this anonymous type.